# Mudar o valor de uma variável ao selecionar um option

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Em minha tabela de produtos, gostaria de fazer alguns filtros básicos, como *ordenar por ordem alfabética, preço, etc...*

> A ideia é a seguinte, quando o usuário selecionar um `option` (não precisa necessariamente ser um option), mudar o valor de uma variável X, mudando também a consulta em meu SQL.

**Exemplo:** (*Apenas para vocês compreenderem melhor*)

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select>
       <option value="a">Ordem A-Z</option>
       <option value="z">Ordem Z-A</option>
       <option value="preco">Ordem por preços</option>
    </select>
</form>
                 
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["a"])){
        $ordenar= "nome_produto";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["z"])){
        $ordenar= "nome_produto DESC";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["preco"])){
        $ordenar= "valor";
    }

// A ideia é mudar o valor diretamente na consulta, ao selecionar algum option...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY $ordenar";
?>
```

Este exemplo, está incompleto, é só um exemplo, mas acho que deu para vocês entenderem o que eu quero fazer.

- É possível eu fazer isso com puro PHP?
- Como eu faria algo parecido que funcione?
- Tem outra maneira mais "prática" ou mais certa do que essa?
- Funcionaria se eu utilizasse Jquery?

Agradeço a qualquer tipo de ajuda, um ótimo dia a todos.

Comment: acredito que a melhor opção seria usando o ajax do jquery, assim, sempre que o option fosse alterado vc buscava o sql em um arquivo php separado de acordo com o option selecionado, outra coisa que reparei é q seu <select>...</select> está errado, está faltando o "name" e no seu php vc teria que chamar o $_POST de acordo com o "name" e não de acordo com cada "value" igual vc fez

Comment: Pensei nessa alternativa, mas para isso eu teria que colocar um `button` do `type submit` dentro do `form` não é? não tem a possibilidade de eu fazer isso sem precisar apertar algum botão? fazer o filtro apenas selecionando o `option`...

Comment: da forma que eu passei vc não precisaria de nenhum botão, vc poderia usar o change() do proprio jquery para verificar se o <select> foi alterado e assim fazer o ajax

Comment: `<select onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()">...</select>`

Comment: Esse trecho fará com que a form seja enviada ao mudar a opção... Não é a melhor forma, mas deve funcionar

Comment: @TalesPeres você pode me dar um exemplo na prática? sou um pouco leigo com js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui fazer a ordenação na tabela dessa forma**

```
<div class="sorting">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <select name="filtro" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="a">Ordem A-Z</option>
            <option value="z">Ordem Z-A</option>
            <option value="preco">Ordem por preços</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$ordernar = 'ID_produtos DESC';

if (isset($_POST["filtro"])){
    $filtro = $_POST['filtro'];

    if ($filtro == "a") {
        $ordernar = 'produto';
    }
    if ($filtro == "z") {
        $ordernar = 'produto DESC';
    }
    if ($filtro == "preco") {
        $ordernar = 'valor';
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY $ordernar";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar um event listener ou diretamente no elemento, uma chamada para o submit do form:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="filtro">
    <select onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()">
       <option value="a">Ordem A-Z</option>
       <option value="z">Ordem Z-A</option>
       <option value="preco">Ordem por preços</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Neste caso, eu selecionei pelo nome da tag, mas em cenarios mais realistas você deveria selecionar por id ou class.

Abaixo você pode executar o código para ver como ficou:

```js
/**
  Simulando envio, ignore
**/

var onSubmit = function(e){
  alert('form enviada');
  return false;
 };

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit = onSubmit;
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" name="filtro">
    <select onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()">
       <option value="a">Ordem A-Z</option>
       <option value="z">Ordem Z-A</option>
       <option value="preco">Ordem por preços</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso o envia o `form` sem precisar de um `button`, porém, como eu faria para entrar na condição do `IF`? (selecionar o `option` e trazer um valor para a variável)

Comment: Se eu consegui entender, nao muda nada. Ao enviar o form, você já está pegando os valores do $_POST. Para manter o valor selecionado, basta adicionar a propriedade `selected` no option que você deseja: `<option value="a"   <?php if(isset($_POST["a"]) echo 'selected'; ?>>Ordem A-Z</option>`

Comment: Nao, pera. Você precisa dar um name pro select, e pegar por ele. Nao `$_POST["a"]`

Comment: Ficaria assim no html: `<select name="filtro">...</select>` e no php: `$_POST["filtro"]`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu acabei fazendo um pouquinho diferente mas consegui baseado em a sua ajuda! Vou colocar a minha resposta abaixo, mas irei considerar a sua. +1